# Sound Designers Vernacular / Nomenclature

Tags: metadata, database, library

I'm looking for a creative way to tag and enter metadata into my database of audio files and synth patches. I realize that any list would be particular to the person creating it but is there a way for to us to collaborate on this site, creating a list of descriptive words and phrases particularly useful in a sound design search database ?

I wondered if there were someway to collect descriptions we could share and vote up similar to how some aspects of this site works IE: when I enter tags for a post it automagically finds similar or same words. For example if 32 people had entered or maybe even voted for "be-jizzle-dazle" as a useful description then it would pop up to the top of a list of useful sound design words & phrases.

Or is there another online tool that might have been built for another purpose that I can co-opt for this task .. ?? Any comment would be awesome .. let me know what you think !

Comment: this would be great, I don't know how hard it would be to programme though. 

Answer (score 2):

I know that in Ric Viers' Sound Effects Bible he has a whole section dedicated to library organization and tagging that's supposed to be pretty good.

Personally, I keep the file named after what the actual source is and when I tag I try to describe the nature of the sound ie: impact, scrape, creak, ambience, atmospheric, sweep, whoosh, wooden, hollow, metal, resonant, bright, dark, creepy, wet, dry, bubbly, thud, etc. I personally try to avoid coming up with lists of what it could be used for. I could spend hours wasting time doing that. I'll only list something like that if it's a very obvious connection. Otherwise I add on potential uses as I use a sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very interested in this as well.  My general principle is to start out by describing what that sound actually was (metal door slam hard ext) and then go into as many textural descriptors as I can (deep thick resonant rattle) and finally if the sound is exception or specific I'll give it another tag (badass) that is uniform to that kind of thing.  My unique tags include badass, blip, ui, foly, and etoll.

Comment: What's ui mean? Like when Snoop Dog says "Ooooweeee"?

Comment: ui = user interface